# TURF analysis package installation in R

Tags: r

Has anyone used TURF analysis in R recently? The documentation http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/turfR/turfR.pdf shows release date of 2015 so I would expect it to work on my R version.

R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)

library(turfR)
Error in library(turfR) : there is no package called ‘turfR’

Answer (score 0):

The package was removed from CRAN over a year ago (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/turfR/index.html)). To install the latest version you can do:

```r
devtools::install_version('turfR', version = '0.8-7')
#> Downloading package from url: 
#>   https://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R//src/contrib/Archive/turfR/turfR_0.8-7.tar.gz
```

Comment: Does anyone know why it was removed? Is it defective?

Comment: @LogOn when you submit a package to CRAN you are responsible for its maintenance. In this case, it seems the CRAN checks on the latest version of R wanted the maintainer to explicitly import some base R functions from the `utils` package, but the maintainer did not respond. In such situtations, it does not mean that the package is defective, but rather that there is no evidence it is currently being maintained. The CRAN checks are very thorough and the particular reason for failing the check was minor, so my guess is that it would be fine to use. I can't guarantee that though.